# Change tag of html with regex when content has specific word in SublimeText

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I have a html with:

```
<p class="s5">Chapter 1 – General Information</p>
<p class="s5">Section 1 – Example</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p class="s5">Chapter 2 – Introduction</p>
```

and I want to replace every `<p class="s5">` tag that starts with `Chapter` for `<h1> ... </h1>`.

How I peform it with regex substitution in SublimeText?

Comment: Beware. A storm is coming: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2615940

Comment: What language are you using?
@skrrgwasme it's a perfectly valid storm.

Comment: @vihan I wasn't trying to make any comment about the validity. I don't understand the nuances of the debate well enough to do so. I just wanted to give the OP some warning of what's to come, because storms do tend to descend upon HTML & regex questions.

Comment: I'm just correcting a PDF that was converted to HTML using SublimeText 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't indicated which language/tool you're using, so here's a generic solution:

```
Search: (?<=<p class="s5">)(Chapter[^<]*)
Replace: <h1>$1</h1>
```

Breakdown:

- `(?<=<p class="s5">)` is a *look behind* (non-consuming assertion) for `<p class="s5">`
- `(Chapter[^<]*)` is text starting with `Chapter` and everything up to the next `<`

If your tool doesn't understand look behinds, you can just consume and replace the preceding input instead:

```
Search: <p class="s5">(Chapter[^<]*)
Replace: <p class="s5"><h1>$1</h1>
```

Note that languages/tool vary with back-reference syntax; the `$1` may need to be `\1` instead.